# Simulate frequent GPS movements in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, gps

I'm creating a swift app which is based on the user's location changes.
While trying to find a way to change the location frequently for testing purposes, I found that I could use Automation in Instruments, and add some Javascript to simulate the changes of location.

However, it looks like Xcode 8 removed Automation from Instruments.

What would be a good alternative besides GPX files ?

I need to be able to test on my iPhone since I also use the camera.

Comment: Do you want to continuously get location update? and do you want to restrict the location changes to particular set of locations?

Comment: I do want to continuously get location updates, but I don't want to restrict the location changes

Comment: Test on a device?

Comment: @matt yes I test on my iphone since I also need the camera